# Problem when moving and changing object pose at the same time

Tags: animation, pose-mode, dopesheet

As you can see in the image below, I can move and rotate the object correctly:

[image]

It turns out, I'd like to move it and change your pose at the same time and I can not do that.

I modified only the position of one of his bones. Without tampering with his position and this happened:

[image]

All the animation (from frame 0 to frame 100) now has the pose I put on frame 100. **Detail that I did not press the 'i' key.**

**That's what I imagined and I wish it would happen after I hit the 'i' key.**

[image]

The 'z' is the same in all the pictures, because I have not changed.

The detail is that I can cause the object to change its pose (in another test), but for this I can not move it and vice versa.

There is a video that I saw and it drew attention to me in one detail. As you can see in the 20:40 minute of the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyVvi-TjHlM&t=1240) => Any modification he makes to the character's bones is immediately marked on the Dope Sheet, but when I make a modification to any of the bones it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, here is what I'd say:

- First, maybe enable the "Only Include Channels Relating to Selected Objects and Data" option (arrow icon in the *Dopesheet*). It will only display, in the *Dopesheet*, the keyframes of the object(s) you've selected in the 3D view, and it will make the things simpler to understand.
- Select the object itself (not the armature). If you go in the *Dopesheet* window, you can see that there's a track called *Cube* > *CubeAction*, and that 2 keyframes have been created for the cube object. I think it's useless and even may create some problems because in your case you've actually created an armature and parented your object to it, so from now on it's the armature that is supposed to move your object! So select these keyframes and delete them.
- Select the armature. If you go in the *Dopesheet*, you can see the *Armature > ArmatureAction* track, it has 2 keyframes. Nice, it's probably what you want, the armature is the parent of the cube and to move the cube you need to move the armature. Keep these keyframes.
- Keep in mind that until now you've just animated the armature in *Object* mode, you haven't moved any bone in *Pose* mode. So until now the armature works like a basic parent, for example like an empty would.
- Now you want to move some bones within the armature. Keep your armature selected and go in *Pose* mode. Rotate the bone you want and press <kbd>i</kbd> to insert a keyframe. In the *Dopesheet*, if you unfold the *Armature* > *ArmatureAction* track, you'll see that a *Bone* track has been created. But before that, no keyframe was created on this track, so if you want your bone to have another position before the one you've created, put your cursor one frame before, press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to reset the bone position, and press <kbd>i</kbd> to insert a keyframe. Now you have 2 keyframes and the bone will have its basic position at the start of the animation.
- You could also have chosen to create the whole movement of your armature (on the X and Y axis) in *Pose* mode, moving the bones from position to position B, instead of creating an object animation, it's a choice that depends on the situation.
- To automatically record a keyframe (i.e. avoid the <kbd>i</kbd> command) you need to press the "Automatic Keyframe Insertion" button in the *Timeline* (red circle icon).

[image]

Comment: I do not know if I did something wrong, but I did not have to delete any keyframe from the armature (because there was nothing, I had not pressed the 'i' key). But I understood everything I have to do. I'll do it tomorrow.

Comment: I did as you told me, except what I reported in the previous comment. Now I got the opposite. The pose changes, but the position does not. I put an edit in my question that might help you to point out to me what I did wrong this time.

Comment: Forget the edit. I was forgetting to put 2 position reference points. Everything worked. Thank you.